# Update all date columns in SQL Server -1 day

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date, datetime

I want to update my database (SQL Server Express) all the dates for specific ids.

I am displaying the ids I want to.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) ID, Dates
FROM tbl_table
WHERE (id IN (29695, 29700, 29701, 29702, 29703, 29704, 29705, 29706, 29707, 29708, 29709, 29710, 29711, 29712, 29713, 29714, 29715))
```

AND my dates in the database are like this:

[image]

Is there any way to update all the date columns with same date - 1 day?

For example: if we have `2019-12-20`, update it to `2019-12-19`?

For example if I want to do it in PHP, I would loop through this query and fetch all all dates. After I would remove one day like this:

```
date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date. ' - 1 days');
```

And create a query to update all the columns based on id. I just want to avoid that. Is there any SQL command that do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The request below will update the rows you want by adding -1 days on each date:

```
UPDATE tbl_table 
SET    dates = Dateadd(day, -1, dates) 
WHERE  id IN ( 29695, 29700, 29701, 29702, 
               29703, 29704, 29705, 29706, 
               29707, 29708, 29709, 29710, 
               29711, 29712, 29713, 29714, 29715 )
```

`DATEADD` function takes 3 parameters:

1. the `interval` ( day, month, year ..)
2. the `increment` (the value to add or remove if negative)
3. an `expression` (wich is a datetime type)

See [DATEADD documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql)

Answer (score 3):

To return a query with the previous day:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) ID, Dates, DATEADD(dd, -1, Dates) AS PreviousDay
FROM tbl_table
```

To update the table with the previous day:

```
UPDATE tbl_table
SET    Dates = DATEADD(dd, -1, Dates)
FROM   -- Put your conditions here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableName SET date= DATEADD(d,-1, date)  
where ....
```

( here you put where clause for you required)